# Move to another activity after clicking on FCM notification if application is in foreground

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I want after clicking on notification, application move to particular activity. It happen when app is in background or isn't running, but when app is in foreground it moves to My MainActivity.

This is how i am sending notification using FCM.

```
            JSONObject root = new JSONObject();

            JSONObject notification = new JSONObject();
            notification.put("body", message);
            notification.put("title", "My Application");
            notification.put("click_action", action);


            JSONObject data = new JSONObject();

            data.put("message", message);
            data.put("user_id", user_id);

            root.put("notification", notification);
            root.put("data", data);
            root.put("to", token);


            String result = postToFCM(root.toString());
```

Comment: What's the value of `action`?

Comment: action is intent_action where i have to navigate after clicking on notification. And it work fine in the case of background or app isn't running.